# Using case and like statment without duplicate results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am trying to use case and like statement. When I run this below query it is duplicating results on some rows where it is y on particular columns. I am using SQL Server 2000.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [rjvn_pound_reference]
    ,t_reference
    ,t_street_name
    ,t_zone_name
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN rjvn_note LIKE '%CORRESPONDENCE%'
                THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
            END
        ) AS CorrespondenceReceived
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN rjvn_note LIKE '%review form complete%'
                THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
            END
        ) AS REVIEWFORMCOMPLETE
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN rjvn_note LIKE '%Manually issued NTO - Drive off%'
                THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
            END
        ) AS ManuallyissuedNTO
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN rjvn_note LIKE '%Manually issued NTK - Drive Off%'
                THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
            END
        ) AS ManuallyissuedNTK
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN rjvn_note LIKE '%Drive off- Final reminder sent%'
                THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
            END
        ) AS finalReminderSent
FROM [ICPS].[dbo].[removal_job_vehicle_notes] AS a
INNER JOIN tickets t ON (a.rjvn_pound_reference = t.t_number)
INNER JOIN dbo.ticket_hold_record thr ON (t.t_number = thr.thr_system_ref)
WHERE thr_hold_type = '2207555'
    AND t.t_contract IN ('18','1')
```

Results:

```
805464  XL05512211  Selby (60-100)  Abbey Walk  N   N   Y   N   N
805464  XL05512211  Selby (60-100)  Abbey Walk  N   Y   N   N   N
805464  XL05512211  Selby (60-100)  Abbey Walk  Y   N   N   N   N
```

But I want this to displayed on single row instead  like:

```
805464  XL05512211  Selby (60-100)  Abbey Walk  Y   Y   Y   N   N.

UPDATED :
944786  XL07075730  Selby (60-100)  Abbey Walk  N   N   N   N   Y   
but I should get
944786  XL07075730  Selby (60-100)  Abbey Walk  N   N   Y   N   Y
```

MY ACTUAL TABLE DATA for that record :

```
rjvn_pound_reference    rjvn_time                 rjvn_userid      rjvn_note
944786                  2014-01-08 10:38:17.000   JAMIED           Vehicle Drove Away During PCN Issue
944786                  2014-01-08 14:22:21.000   ADRIANJ          Correspondent Scanned
944786                  2014-02-05 15:44:53.000   ELLIED           Manually issued NTO drive off
944786                  2015-03-12 10:16:53.000   KATIEB           Drive off- Final reminder sent

--manually issued NTO drive off is displayed as 'N' instead of 'y'
```

Comment: GROUP BY, with  MAX(case...), MAX(case...)

Comment: Can you give us your table data and definitions, there might be a much simpler solution but because I'm staring blind at that giant query there it's hard to start looking for a solution

Comment: By saying `SELECT DISTINCT` at the beginning of your statement, you are telling your `CASE WHEN` statement to give you a new unique line every time your column meets/doesn't meet your criteria. `GROUP BY` @jarlh may help, but I'm not seeing how your `WHERE` clause gives you the three line result you are finding. How are your tables structured?

Comment: Is this required to be done in a single statement (`VIEW`) or can it be done in multiple statements (as in a `STORED PROCEDURE`)?

Comment: Sorry jarlh, the query did not do the trick ...ignore previous comment..code updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the column references in the query are not qualified (to indicate *which* table they are returned from), and because we don't have a schema definition to go through to sort it out...  we can't tell what table the `rjvn_note` column comes from.

As far as getting "duplicate" rows, the most likely explanation is a `JOIN`, there's a one-to-many association, and multiple rows are being returned. This is expected behavior.

To "collapse" rows, you can add a **`GROUP BY`** to the end of the query. You can also use aggregate functions (like **`MIN()`** or **`MAX()`**) to "pick out" values returned by expressions from the collapsed rows.

The **`DISTINCT`** keyword (as in your query) operates on the *entire* set of expressions in the SELECT list. That will eliminate rows that are exact duplicates.

There's a couple of other alternatives that are useful in some situations. For example, using as an **`EXISTS`** predicate (it the requirement is test for the existence of a row in a related table, without producing "duplicates" like a `JOIN` operation would. Or, using a subquery in the `SELECT` list.

Because the column references are not qualified, and because we don't have a schema definition, we're really just guessing. Some of the "maybe try this" guesses might turn out to be right, but they are just guesses.

---

Here's my "guess" at the changes you need to make to the query to get the specified resultset:

- Ditch the `DISTINCT` keyword
- Add `MAX()` aggregate around the CASE expressions
- Add a `GROUP BY` clause listing all non-aggregate expressions from the SELECT list
- (optional) Qualify ALL column references with a table alias (several good reasons to do this: as an aid to future readers, and insulate the statement from future failure

```
SELECT a.rjvn_pound_reference
     , t.t_reference
     , t.t_street_name
     , t.t_zone_name
     , MAX(CASE WHEN a.rjvn_note LIKE   '%CORRESPONDENCE%'
                THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
       ) AS CorrespondenceReceived
     , MAX(CASE WHEN a.rjvn_note LIKE   '%review form complete%'
                THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
       ) AS REVIEWFORMCOMPLETE
     , MAX(CASE WHEN a.rjvn_note LIKE   '%Manually issued NTO - Drive off%'
                THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
       ) AS ManuallyissuedNTO
     , MAX(CASE WHEN a.rjvn_note LIKE   '%Manually issued NTK - Drive Off%'
                THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'END
       ) AS ManuallyissuedNTK
     , MAX(CASE WHEN a.rjvn_note LIKE   '%Drive off- Final reminder sent%'
                THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
       ) AS finalReminderSent
  FROM [ICPS].[dbo].[removal_job_vehicle_notes] a
  JOIN [tickets] t
    ON t.t_number = a.rjvn_pound_reference
  JOIN [dbo].[ticket_hold_record] thr 
    ON thr_system_ref = t.t_number
 WHERE thr.thr_hold_type = '2207555'
   AND t.t_contract IN ('18','1')
 GROUP
    BY a.rjvn_pound_reference
     , t.t_reference
     , t.t_street_name
     , t.t_zone_name
```

Comment: Nicely said, @spencer7593. I think as you suggested EXISTS seems to be a good option to explore for this situation since the join has a one-to-many relationship in the above query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT [RJVN_POUND_REFERENCE],
  T_REFERENCE,
  T_STREET_NAME,
  T_ZONE_NAME,
  DECODE(MAX(CASE WHEN RJVN_NOTE LIKE '%CORRESPONDENCE%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 1, 'Y', 'N') AS CORRESPONDENCERECEIVED,
  DECODE(MAX(CASE WHEN RJVN_NOTE LIKE '%review form complete%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 1, 'Y', 'N') AS REVIEWFORMCOMPLETE,
  DECODE(MAX(CASE WHEN RJVN_NOTE LIKE '%Manually issued NTO - Drive off%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 1, 'Y', 'N') AS MANUALLYISSUEDNTO,
  DECODE(MAX(CASE WHEN RJVN_NOTE LIKE '%Manually issued NTK - Drive Off%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 1, 'Y', 'N') AS MANUALLYISSUEDNTK,
  DECODE(MAX(CASE WHEN RJVN_NOTE LIKE '%Drive off- Final reminder sent%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 1, 'Y', 'N') AS FINALREMINDERSENT
FROM [ICPS].[DBO].[REMOVAL_JOB_VEHICLE_NOTES] AS A
INNER JOIN TICKETS T
ON(A.RJVN_POUND_REFERENCE=T.T_NUMBER)
INNER JOIN DBO.TICKET_HOLD_RECORD THR
ON(T.T_NUMBER=THR.THR_SYSTEM_REF)
WHERE THR_HOLD_TYPE='2207555'
  AND T.T_CONTRACT IN('18', '1')
GROUP BY [RJVN_POUND_REFERENCE],
  T_REFERENCE,
  T_STREET_NAME,
  T_ZONE_NAME
```

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is no `DECODE` function in SQL Server.

Comment: HI Tim, I tried your query but I got an error as 'DECODE' is not a recognized function name. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Max in your case statement and group by like @jarlh suggested should work for you:

```
SELECT q1.[rjvn_pound_reference]
    ,q1.t_reference
    ,q1.t_street_name
    ,q1.t_zone_name
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN q1.CorrespondenceReceived = 1
                THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
            END
        ) CorrespondenceReceived
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN q1.REVIEWFORMCOMPLETE = 1
                THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
            END
        ) REVIEWFORMCOMPLETE
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN q1.ManuallyissuedNTO = 1
                THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
            END
        ) ManuallyissuedNTO
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN q1.ManuallyissuedNTK = 1
                THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
            END
        ) ManuallyissuedNTK
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN q1.finalReminderSent = 1
                THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
            END
        ) finalReminderSent
FROM (
    SELECT [rjvn_pound_reference]
        ,t_reference
        ,t_street_name
        ,t_zone_name
        ,MAX(CASE 
                WHEN rjvn_note LIKE '%CORRESPONDENCE%'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END) AS CorrespondenceReceived
        ,MAX(CASE 
                WHEN rjvn_note LIKE '%review form complete%'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END) AS REVIEWFORMCOMPLETE
        ,MAX(CASE 
                WHEN rjvn_note LIKE '%Manually issued NTO - Drive off%'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END) AS ManuallyissuedNTO
        ,MAX(CASE 
                WHEN rjvn_note LIKE '%Manually issued NTK - Drive Off%'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END) AS ManuallyissuedNTK
        ,MAX(CASE 
                WHEN rjvn_note LIKE '%Drive off- Final reminder sent%'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END) AS finalReminderSent
    FROM [ICPS].[dbo].[removal_job_vehicle_notes] AS a
    INNER JOIN tickets t ON (a.rjvn_pound_reference = t.t_number)
    INNER JOIN dbo.ticket_hold_record thr ON (t.t_number = thr.thr_system_ref)
    WHERE thr_hold_type = '2207555'
        AND t.t_contract IN (
            '18'
            ,'1'
            )
    GROUP BY [rjvn_pound_reference]
        ,t_reference
        ,t_street_name
        ,t_zone_name
    ) q1
```

Comment: HI Nepali this query is giving me  error like  on first line  Incorrect syntax near ';'. is this query can be run on sql server 2000 mgmt studio

Comment: Please try it again. Sometimes `with` statement acts goofy with or without semi colon. :) I am not sure if SQL Server 2000 has WITH Clause feature, I doubt it though!

Comment: HI Nepali thanks for the query but  with function cannot be used sql server mgmt studio. It always throws an syntax error.

Comment: You are absolutely right. WITH clause came in with SQL Server 2005 Release. I have updated my answer with a subquery instead, hopefully it should work for you this time. Also, I believe it is a good practice to convert your string to int to get your max and min value, instead of using those functions for string values directly.